# Why does "\e034" appear in css but does not create a tick icon?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```html
    <style>
         .icons:before {
            content: "\e034";
            color: #00bc9b;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-top: -1px;
            margin-left: -1px
        }
    </style>
 
    <span class="icons"> </span>
```

[image]

The above code should show an icon like this, but it is not displaying that icon.

Answer (score 3):

are you using FontAwesome??? If so, you are missing `font-family: FontAwesome`, please put it into your code:

```
     .icons:before {
        content: "\e034";
        color: #00bc9b;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
    }
```

EDIT: Make sure you have the font set under your project

Answer (score 2):

```
\e034
```

is a bootstrap `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"> </span>`Properties
like this `.glyphicon-flag:before { content: "\e034";}` which helps to create flag icon

But if you want to create check mark as above image you can use font awesome

```css
.fa.fa-check-square{
  
            color: #00bc9b;
            font-size: 50px;
            margin-top: -1px;
            margin-left: -1px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/79a4552de1.js"></script>



<i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what icon font set and\or library are you using, Therefore it is close to impossible to be sure.

In case you would like to get the same visual icon with FontAwesome (free, and has many other cool icons) then please check the following link:

http://fontawesome.io/icon/check-square

Add font awesome to your page head (this is an example, use your own font-awesome CDN url):

**HTML head**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6f6d569d5c.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    .....
```

**HTML body**

```
<i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Hope it helps a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Is an square symbol from UTF-8 representing you are missing some value. If you are trying to use an icon library, and the reference is bad, will show this.
For more reference about the character you can go to:
http://www.utf8icons.com/character/57396/UTF-8-character